# How do i redirect to add address page after registration on Prestashop 1.7.4?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I need the address to be added directly after user registrations if it is not done through the checkout page!

Thanks

Comment: I think an example of what you need could be much better to understand what you need.

Comment: with PS 1.7 when a new user registers the address fields are not included in the registration page, you simply have to go the profile page and from there add the address after the registration

But I want all the registered users to always at least have one address!
So what I actually need is to have the address fields included in the registration page.

But I thought maybe a simple solution for this is to redirect the user directly after registration to the add address page.

Or another way is to figure out how to use the same principle when a new user is registering from the cart page

Comment: Ok I understand now, I must say that make this; (`Or another way is to figure out how to use the same principle when a new user is registering from the cart page`) of course is not easy, the easy way is by a module hooked in the header which validate the registered customers that have at least one address added or not and then forces a redirection a the creation.